# Livingstyleguide compile task never finishes

Tags: sass, rubygems, npm, gulp

I have a VERY simple test site where I'm trying to experiment with the Livingstyleguide gem (https://github.com/livingstyleguide/livingstyleguide).

The problem is that when I run `livingstyleguide compile my_src_file.lsg my_dest_file.html` from the command line, the process hangs and the task is never carried out. There are no errors logged to the terminal window, so I'm not sure how to even start debugging this.

I've tried implementing livingstyleguide via Gulp as well, and running my task to create the style guide also fails from there. That DOES output an error, the details of which are as follows:

```
Error in plugin 'gulp-livingstyleguide'

Message:
    Command failed: 
Details:
    killed: false
    code: 10
    signal: null
```

This is pretty cryptic, so I'm still not even sure what's failing.

Here's my gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var livingstyleguide = require('gulp-livingstyleguide');

gulp.task('sass', function(){
    return gulp.src('scss/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch('scss/*.scss', ['sass']);
});

gulp.task('lsg', function(){
    gulp.src('scss/styleguide.html.lsg')
        .pipe(livingstyleguide())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app'));
});
```

If I comment out the `livingstyleguide()` line in my gulpfile, the `lsg` task takes the src file and outputs it into the app directory, so I know that the paths to the files are correct, and it's just something with the plugin or permissions or something that's causing everything to fail.

Any help would be very, very appreciated!